# Django annotate returning unexpected Sum value

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

These are my models:

```
class Consume(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField(default=1)
    entry_for = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='consume_entry_for',
    )


class Purchase(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0.00
    )
    entry_for = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='ledger_entry_for',
    )
```

and this is my query:

```
person_wise_total = Person.objects.annotate(
            total_purchase=Coalesce(Sum('ledger_entry_for__amount'), Value(0)),
            total_consume=Coalesce(Sum('consume_entry_for__amount'), Value(0))
        )
```

For example, i have an entry in `Purchase`

```
amount: 2, entry_for: jhon,
amount: 3, entry_for: smith
amount: 5, entry_for: jhon,
amount: 1, entry_for: jhon,
```

and `consume` entry:

```
amount: 1, entry_for: jhon,
amount: 2, entry_for: smith,
```

According to above data, my query Sum should return `total_consume` for jhon is `1`, but it is returning `3` for jhon in total_consume and smith total_consume is `2`, here smith result is expected but jhon result is unexpected.

I guess, the problem/ wrong calculation occurring because of jhon has `3` entry in the Purchase table, so it is multpliying with total entry of person's purchase and total consume amount, i am not sure why.

Can anyone please help me how can i get the correct calculated result?

I want, it should return,

```
jhon's total_purchase: 8, total_consume: 1,
smith's total_purchase: 3, total_consume: 2
```

can anyone help me in case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django uses joins tables instead of subqueries when there are multiple aggregations as documented already [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations)

> Combining multiple aggregations with annotate() will [yield the wrong results](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060) because joins are used instead of subqueries

You should write [subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) for each aggregation